# How to model similar named predicates or attributes for nodes in dgraph?

Tags: graph-databases, dgraph

I am trying to use Dgraph as my primary database. I have a simple system that has two domain entities viz. `User` and `Product`. They both have certain properties represented as **edges/attributes** in Dgraph. They both have a common property **name** which is a **string**. If I use the same predicate `name` for both the nodes then it creates a problem when I am using a `has` function to find all the users with a `name` edge. The **has** function also returns `Product` nodes with `name` edge. This is not desirable.

In this situation, what is the right approach or recommendation when modeling the domain entities? I can think of two approaches:

1. Have a common edge `type` for all the nodes to uniquely identify similar nodes. Here the value of `type` would be `User` or `Product`. This is approximately similar to a traditional table/column analogy where `type` represents the `table` and `edges` as columns with a context localized to `type` property.
2. Have a separate predicate for each node type. So, instead of having `name`, prefer two predicates like `user_name` and `product_name`.

I believe this problem only exists for RDF/Triplestore databases like Dgraph and not for property graphs like Neo4j since each node contains its own properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news! In [Dgraph](https://dgraph.io) v1.1, [types were introduced.](https://docs.dgraph.io/query-language/#type-system)

You may assign a **type** `User` and `Product` to your entities and filter at query time by doing:

```
{
  q(func: type(User)) {
    uid
    name
  }
}
```

**Before v1.1**

For the sake of simplicity, I would assign unique names as you describe at point 2.

Should you still like to have a shared property label like *name*, doing what you propose at point 1 will be ok.

Query could look like this:

```
{
  q(func: has(kind)) {
    pred @filter(user) {
      uid
      name
    }
  }
}
```